# Null values with OR condition inside jsx expression is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logical-operators, logical-or

I have a piece of code that is supposed to render a component, or a placeholder div.

I've placed this inside the return block of another component, but I can't figure out why the placeholder div never renders.

Here is the piece of code in the return block mentioned:

```
{renderBannerSummary() || <div className={spacer} />}
```

renderBannerSummary is a function that renders a component that sometimes returns null.

I can see that null is indeed being returned on occasion via the console
[image]

I can also see that if I extract the logical OR statement entirely, and log it out, it logs the div whenever renderBannerSummary returns null, as expected:
[image]

So, my question is, why is it that the spacer div is never shown in the UI when renderBannerSummary returns null/is falsy?
Instead, nothing renders at all.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you show the code of `renderBannerSummary`, or, even better, a reproducible minimal example in a codesandbox? From what you shared, there is no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: And are you sure that the div doesn't render? Maybe it does but with size 0 or such.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```js
{ renderBannerSummary() ? renderBannerSummary():<div className={spacer} /> }
```

This code will render `<div className={spacer}/>` if `renderBannerSummary()` is *null*, *undefined* or *false*

Comment: If `renderBannerSummary()` has a side effect then this will run the side effect *two* times.

Comment: in production or dev mode?

Comment: If `renderBannerSummary` has a side effect, that is a problem in itself because there shouldn't be side effects during rendering.

Comment: this code should work even with a side effect

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my conditional OR expression will never return the right hand side, as curly braces {} within the render part of a component will always trigger the code, meaning that my method call will always trigger, thus always being true - within the {}, my code was not conditional

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your `or condition` `||`, but it all depends on your function that might return `null`

so you've the condition(inside jsx expression)

```
{ mightReturnNull() || <div>spacer</div> }
```

if `mightReturnNull` is written like this

```
function mightReturnNull(){
  return null;
}
```

it will always render the `spacer`

but if `mightReturnNull` is written like this

```
function mightReturnNull(){
  return <>{null}</>;
}
```

it basically returns a fragment element(or any wrapper element of your choice) and that's of course not a `null` and those it's not a `falsy` value, that's why you'll end up rendering the left-hand side, because it's a `truthy` value